# tqdm._tqdm.TqdmKeyError: "Unknown argument(s): {'unit_divisor': 1024}"

Tags: python, pypi, twine

I am trying to upload my library to `Pypi` via `twine` and I am getting some error that is related to `tqdm`. Can anyone please help.

The command is `twine upload dist/*`

`twine version 1.13.0`

`python version 3.6`

Error :

```
TqdmKeyError("Unknown argument(s): " + str(kwargs)))
tqdm._tqdm.TqdmKeyError: "Unknown argument(s): {'unit_divisor': 1024}"
```

Full Traceback :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pai/.local/bin/twine", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
  File "/home/pai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twine/__main__.py", line 28, in main
    return dispatch(sys.argv[1:])
  File "/home/pai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twine/cli.py", line 77, in dispatch
    return main(args.args)
  File "/home/pai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twine/commands/upload.py", line 127, in main
    return upload(upload_settings, args.dists)
  File "/home/pai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twine/commands/upload.py", line 88, in upload
    resp = repository.upload(package)
  File "/home/pai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twine/repository.py", line 163, in upload
    resp = self._upload(package)
  File "/home/pai/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/twine/repository.py", line 146, in _upload
    disable=self.disable_progress_bar) as bar:
  File "/home/pai/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tqdm/_tqdm.py", line 662, in __init__
    TqdmKeyError("Unknown argument(s): " + str(kwargs)))
tqdm._tqdm.TqdmKeyError: "Unknown argument(s): {'unit_divisor': 1024}"
```

**Update :**

The error was because of the older version of `tqdm`. I had `tqdm==4.11.0` while `twine` requires `tqdm>=4.2.4`. By installing the latest version the problem is solved

Comment: can you show the full traceback

Comment: @AnthonySottile I just realised it's due to the older verision of `tqdm`(4.11.4). Now I upraded to 4.39 and now everything is working fine. Should I delete the quest?

Comment: @AnthonySottile Reference Link https://github.com/pypa/twine/issues/385

Comment: You could [self-answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) by providing the version that you used, quoting the relevant parts of the Github issue, and providing the link as reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is due to an older version of `tqdm` . `twine` requires `tqdm>=4.24.0` .

So you can install the latest version of `tqdm` to solve the issue(as per today it is 4.39.0)

```
pip install twine==4.39.0
```